# AngularJS: validation not working

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am trying to check from the actor name based on the movie clicked. If the movie i clicked has no actors it should show an error message but mine its still showing an empty table with the table heads only. Are there any ways to validate it? The same code i tried in my film listing by category its working. Thanks in advance.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-show="actor.length">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Actor Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="actor in actors" data-ng-show="showSuccessMessage">
        <td>
            {{actor.first_name + " " + actor.last_name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h4 ng-show="!actor.length">No actors available in this movie</h4>
```

Comment: did you mean `!actors.length`? (plural)

Comment: That's it, except without the `!`.

Comment: @rgvassar i tried both actors and actor it didnt worked....

Comment: `ng-show="actors.length"` did not work?

Comment: just now i tried it didnt worked but suddenly its working again.. thats really weird

Comment: @JainishJariwala might be...

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `ng-show="actors.length"` and `ng-show="!actors.length`